# react-minimal-pie-chart Border segment

Tags: reactjs

Hi I need to create react pie chart with border how can i create this

```
import { PieChart } from 'react-minimal-pie-chart'


const chartData = [
      { title: 'Completed', value: completed, color: 'var(--Green-01)', border: '4px solid red' },
      { title: 'active', value: active, color: 'var(--Primary-10)', border: '4px solid red' },
    ]

<PieChart
                      paddingAngle={0}
                      labelStyle={{
                        fontWeight: 700,
                        fontSize: '0.85rem',
                        fill: 'var(--Dark-01)',
                      }}
                      labelPosition={0}
                      segmentsStyle={{
                        border: '4px solid red',
                      }}
                      lineWidth={35}
                      label={({ dataEntry }) => {
                        if (dataEntry.title === 'Completed') {
                          return (
                            Math.round(dataEntry.value) +
                            '% ' +
                            I18n.t(`home_dashBoad_completed_per_label`)
                          )
                        }
                      }}
                      // viewBoxSize={[100, 50]}
                      data={chartData}
                    />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have faced this same issue but did not find any perfect solution as per 'react-minimal-pie-chart' doc.

So I created border with separate functionality and this worked for me.

Check this [codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-minimal-pie-chart-with-border-jz5knb?file=/src/App.js).

Hope it's helpful!